# django: refresh with an invalid form

Tags: django, forms, submit, refresh

The problem is when refreshing the page with an invalid form (with errors displayed on the page) I get "Confirm Form Resubmission" alert and hitting 'ok' I end up with the same invalid form with errors. This behavior seems a bit strange to me, I suppose I should get an empty form.

In case the form is submitted (by pressing the submit button) I get a POST request and process that POST request in my view function. I do check my form's validity. In case it is valid I HttpResponseRedirect to the success page, in case not, I respond with that invalid form (in order to not loose the users data and have errors displayed on the page). This is the expected behavior of the view function (at least to me). 
BUT the problem is that the refresh also "triggers" POST request. This is strange, if someone could explain why refresh triggers that alert and sends a POST request, I'd be many thankful. I'm new to web and eager to understand what is going under the hood. 
So, as in my view function I get the same POST than I have to go the same way as well as with the "submit button" case, right? I can't "distinguish" whether it was a submit or a refresh? I've dumped the request dict for both cases, those are identical.

What I'm missing here? I've done lot of search for this but couldn't get any answers. In almost every case I end up with a case of valid form with suggestion to use HttpResponseRedirect, all right, but what if the form is invalid? User has entered some invalid data then he/she decides to start with a new empty form. The only way now is to click on the url and hit enter. Shall he/she be able to do this with refresh?

Lot of thanks for your answers.
Regards,
Karen

P.S. Here is the code:

```
class TireFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'tire_form.html'
    form_class = TireForm
    success_url = '/tires/tire/thanks'
    initial = {'make': MAKE_CHOICES[0][1]}

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.form_class(request=request, initial=self.initial)
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST, request = request)

    if form.is_valid():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)

    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

HTML
...<form action="">...
```

Comment: Would you mind showing a cut down version of your code that demonstrates this please? it will be much easier to find the issue

Comment: @Sayse - Added, thanks!

Comment: Do you have the html form too? Or at least just the `<form action="">` line, the rest isn't really important

Comment: I'm also not entirely sure that its a problem that needs solving (at least for our website), our users don't ever have a need to refresh the screen when they're trying to send a form, if they did then sending the form to get invalid back again wouldn't be an issue for us

Comment: @Sayse, it's as you wrote - <form action="">.